# What is the equivalent option in Ubuntu for OS X ln -h?

Tags: ubuntu, ln

The osx command: ln -sfh /a/b /c/d

Fails in ubuntu since h is not a valid option

What's the equivalent command options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-n` is used in GNU to prevent dereferencing symlinks

```
ln -sfn /a/b /c/d
```